# Sum Of Total Time Taken Of Timer

Tags: android, timer

I am making a game.

Lets say that it has 2 levels.
I have a TIMER in both which works properly. The code for timer:

```
public Timer t;
public int TimeCounter = 0;
t = new Timer();
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtcount);
                t.setText(String.valueOf(TimeCounter));
                TimeCounter++;
            }
        });
    }
}, 1000, 1000);
```

Now in my 3rd activity i want the total time (Adding the first activity's and second activity's time taken) to be shown.

Also, I want to save the time the user took as the high score.  And then when the user takes less time than the highest score,  the previous will get deleted and the new will be saved

I would appreciate your help.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `TimeCounter` `static`

```
public static int TimeCounter = 0;
```

Now you can increment it in both of your activities like (in second activity it will retain values from first activity)

```
ActivityOne.TimeCounter++;
```

Wherever you want to get its value you can get it easily.

Comment: Please see the edited question. I have 1 more question and if you know,  then please answer me.

Comment: @Devam03: You should use `SharedPreference` to store the time. At every submit update the value.

Comment: I used it, it gets turned into 0 everytime i close and start the app

Comment: @Devam03: It shouldn't. Please post a new question with code of saving and retrieving from shared pref and I ll be happy to help.

Comment: Do you put the value from shared pref to `TimeCounter` when app starts? otherwise it will reset to 0  because that's what you have in declaration.

Comment: No bro, i am posting question w8